# installing cargo-generate failed

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo

My machine is MacOS Catalina.

I tried to make Rust+Wasm app by reading this tutorial
https://rustwasm.github.io/book/game-of-life/setup.html

when I tried to install cargo-generate,I put

```
cargo install cargo-generate
```

Then I got error like bellow

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
 
error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `libc`

error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
 
error: aborting due to previous error

error: failed to compile `cargo-generate v0.5.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/_g/pmx2dld53_5973hz_m4_fy180000gp/T/cargo-installOe8wOn`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

I spent a few days but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Try `sudo xcode-select --install` or `sudo xcode-select --reset` and then `cargo clean`